# Form submission doesn't work over SSL - net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: php, html, forms, ssl, https

We started using TLS 1.2 SSL certificate but suddenly my contact form stopped working.

Chrome console shows:

```
POST https://website.com/send.php net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

`index.html` and `send.php` are in the same directory. I use `.htaccess` file to redirect sessions from **http** to **https**.
Form data is submitted to iframe by:

```
<form id="mat-form" method="post" action="https://website.com/send.php" target="submitted"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Submitted data never arrives by email as it's blocked somehow. How can I solve this?

Comment: Sounds like your script might be responding with a redirect to a non-HTTPS location. Go inspect the response in the network panel to confirm.

Comment: "Failed to load response data".